# Why not @NotNull anotation remove the warning?

Tags: java, annotations, warnings, notnull

I have wrote a class that implements the comparable interface. I used `@NotNull` annotation to suppress the waring in the method parameter. But it still shows a warning.The IDE automatically import this package `com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull` for the `@NotNull`. Why this is happing? Without using this annotation how to remove this warning ?
  I am using Inteij Ultimate with java 8 SE.
Here is my code snippet.[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding @Nonnull (javax.annotation.Nonnull) to the `compareTo` method.

Comment: Correct, `javax.annotation.NonNull` is the right one.

Comment: @uraimo I can not see any annotation like `NotNull` or `Nonnull` in the `javax.annotation` package. When i am trying to write down `javax.annotation.NotNull` or `javax.annotation.Nonnull` then a error occur.

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry but this question is a bit prone to typos :)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, you should be using

```
public int compareTo(@NonNull Node node) {
```

instead of

```
public int compareTo(@NotNull Node node) {
```

The compiler can determine cases where a code path might receive a null value, without ever having to debug a `NullPointerException`.

From [here.](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type)

For these annotations you need [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#installation) installed. Or you can try what the other answer says.

Comment: Not an android question, even if the ide is in dark-mode :)

Comment: @uraimo whoops, im in the wrong tag! xD I'll change it.

Comment: @uraimo Edited definition/link to be more relevent to OP :)

Comment: Good God... i think all permutations are actually available as real classes... NotNull, NonNull, Notnull,etc... his issues is that he didn't import one of the annotations accepted by IntelliJ.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no such thing `Nonnull`. I also try to import `javax.annotation.` package but there is no such annotation like `Nonnull` or `NotNull`. Is there any problem with my jdk version ? I am using currently java version "1.8.0_45".

Comment: Update answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Change your import, you can use intellij's own `com.intellij.annotations.NotNull`, `javax.annotation.Nonnull` or `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`.

This is an IntelliJ feature and it was actually possible to configure which nullable/notnull annotation to use, see [this guide](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/more-flexible-and-configurable-nullublenotnull-annotations/).

If this doesn't fix it, and the message seems to imply this, try removing the `@override`, you are adding an annotation to a parameter that didn't have it in the super class.

Comment: In `javax.annotation` package there is not `@NotNull` or `@Nonnull` annotation. I have changed the configuration according to your given link but my ide still can not find those annotation in that package.

Comment: [I have these annotations](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.annotation/3.1) except `ManagedBean`.